# When i link the C++ project with gradle it comes an error

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk

When I link the C++ project with gradle it comes an error.

[image: Error]

Project Structure
[image: NDK Path]

SDK Tools
[image: Tools]

How can I solve this error?

Comment: First thing you should try is to not use any paths that contain spaces. Android Studio's project wizard even warns you not to use spaces in the project path since it can cause problems with NDK tools.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not post **images** of an error message, but instead, post the **actual text** of the error message in your question post.