# When i link C++ project with gradle the error comes "ERROR: exception while building Json "

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk

When i link C++ project with gradle the error comes "ERROR: exception while building Json ".

[image]

Project Structure
[image]

SDK Tools
[image]

How can I solve this error? give a solution for this.

Comment: Have your other question about C++  solved?

Comment: There is similar question with this one

Comment: Did you know the answer?

Comment: Does this site help you? https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code

Comment: I already  followed this. But , it not works.

Comment: Clean and rebuild the project, maybe it works

Comment: How to clean and rebuild the project Explain.

Comment: Go to Build toolbar of ANdroid Studio, you will see this

Comment: But , it comes the same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209742/discussion-between-mohammadmoeingolchin-and-pradeep-simba).

Comment: Is this question related to your [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60716381/when-i-link-the-c-project-with-gradle-it-comes-an-error) question? Or are they different? If you do not receive adequate answers or feedback, it is not recommended to post multiple times about the same topic. Instead, you can ask for clarification in the comments, [improve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) your question, or offer a bounty on your question.

Comment: Squareskittles did you know answer  for this question?

Comment: @PradeepSimba No, the issue is unclear, from the images you provided. The error message is cut off and not visible. Can you please post the *full* error message in your question post *as text*? You should also describe *all* of the steps you took to setup your project, including any CMake code or installation commands you ran, to provide more context for this problem.

Comment: I edided the question.